# Count and echo number of rows

Tags: pdo, rowcount

Here I want to echo out number of rows the following code shows syntax error

```
 $check=$db->prepare("SELECT count (*) FROM follow WHERE uid_fk=:user_id");
 $check->execute(array(':user_id'=>$user_id));
 echo $check->rowCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) follow WHERE uid_fk=:user_id"; 
$result = $con->prepare($sql); 
$result->execute(); 
$rowCount = $result->fetchColumn();
```